# keeping dialog above activities

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I have an application that depends on connection It has many Activities.I need to display a progress re-connection dialog whenever connection goes down and keep It till connection get back or user dismiss regardless the running Activity. I made this method which intercept the connection failure event In the BaseActivity which Is the parent of all my Activities:

```
public void xmppConnectionClosed() {
            connectionError = true;
            onScreenActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initiateReconnectionDialog(onScreenActivity); //onScreenActivity is singlton represent the current activity 
                    reconnectionDialog.setMessage(onScreenActivity
                            .getString(R.string.reconnectionDialogReconnecting));
                    reconnectionDialog
                            .setStatus(ReconnectionStatus.RECONNECTING);
                    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
                        reconnectionDialog.show();

                }

            });

        }
```

Its onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (connectionError) {
            initiateReconnectionDialog(this);
            reconnectionDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

the Issue now is that If I have Activity A start Activity B when I rotate the device the the onCreate of activity A is called and if I tried to show the dialog it throws an exception that It is not the foreground activity.
Any Ideas how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Dialog that would have to be brought up from a background service. This has to be the case because you don't care if the activity is running. The activity would have to start the service and would run in the background.

Comment: This sound good but what about the issue that showing dialog when rotate the device

Comment: A dialog superceeds all views and as such will NOT be changed when orientation changes. Please read your documentation.

Comment: Because a background service is starting a dialog, it does not need an activity nor is it affects by the orientation of that activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could dismiss the dialog in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance. You should be able to recreate the dialog in your Activity's on create then.